# this.state.annonces.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update State variable on react, when i set it by default my map function work well. But now when i update my state variable with setState i have the response map is not a function here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

class Corps extends React.Component{

    state = {
      annonces : [
        {
          nom : " Karim Ngami",
          annonces: " selon le CEO de google Mr Karim Ngami google lens prends une nouvelle tournure"
        },
        {
          nom : " Brigitte Bami",
          annonces: "Je n'ai jamais douté de mon fils, je savais qu'il sera un grand home"
        },
        {
          nom : "Gladice Ngami",
          annonces: "Le monde est étonné par ces proesses, mais nous non (rire) il savait clairement ou il allait"
        },

      ]
    }

    addAnonces = () =>{

      this.setState({
        annonces : this.state.annonces.push({
          nom : "Nkodi Ngami",
          annonces: "Le monde est étonné par ces proesses, mais nous non (rire) il savait clairement ou il allait"
        })
      })

      console.log(this.state.annonces.length);
    }

    render(){



      return(<div>
                <h5>Mes annonces</h5>
                <div className ="row">

                   <div className="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1">
                        listes

                      {this.state.annonces.map((item) =>(
            <div className ="row"> 
              <div className="col-sm-4">
                <span>{item.nom} :</span>

              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-1">
                <span>{item.annonces}</span>
              </div>
            </div>) 
            )}
                  <button className="btn-success" onClick={this.addAnonces}> Envoyé </button>
                   </div>
                   <div className="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1">
                        <form>
                            <label for="nom">Votre nom:</label> <input type="text" id="nom" /><br/>
                            <label for="texte">votre annonce:</label><textarea placeholder="Ecrivez votre annonce" name="texte" id="texte">
                            </textarea><br/>

                        </form>
                   </div>
                </div> 
             </div>
            );  
    }
}

export default Corps;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lays on your addAnnonces method

**`this.state.annonces.push({ nom: "nom4", annonces: "annonce4" })`** will add a row in your **`announces`** array but react will not take it as state change and it will not effect on UI too. React will only know the state change by **`setState(...)`**

Another stuff is though your are try to assign using **`this.setState(...)`** 
 but  **`this.state.annonces.push(...)`** will return length of array not the array itself

So by this following code you actually assign the length of array to the state change and react get it as **`integer`** rather **`array`** and hence your .map fall into a trouble

```
addAnonces = () =>{
   this.setState({
       annonces : this.state.annonces.push({...})
```

If you really want to do the change in a single line of your array you may try following code

```
addAnnonces = () => {
    this.setState({
      annonces: [...this.state.annonces, { nom: "nom4", annonces: "annonce4" }]
    });
  };
```

Hope you got the idea

Comment: wooooww thank you very much i got my mistake now

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `.map` is a method which can only be called on an array. When you are calling `setState` in your case you are actually setting `annonces` to be the return of `array.push` which I am pretty sure is the length of the array, which is a number. A number is of course not an array which is why you no longer can call `.map`.

What you want to do is set `announces` to be a new array that contains the new value and the old values. You can use the spread operator for this and your code would look something like this.

```
const stateCopy = [...this.state.annonces];
stateCopy.push({
    nom : "Nkodi Ngami",
    annonces: "Le monde est étonné par ces proesses, mais nous non (rire) il savait clairement ou il allait"
})

this.setState({annonces: stateCopy});
```

Of course this is a verbose way of doing this, but it should highlight 2 things.

1)You are now not setting announces to a number, but rather an array

2)You are not mutating the array, but rather creating a copy of the original and passing the new one to `setState`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to modify react state directly.
You can try something like this:

```
  addAnonces = () => {
    // make a copy of this.state.annonces
    const newAnnonces = [...this.state.annonces];
    newAnnonces.push({
      nom: 'Nkodi Ngami',
      annonces: 'Le monde est étonné par ces proesses, mais nous non (rire) il savait clairement ou il allait',
    });
    this.setState({
      annonces: newAnnonces,
    });

    console.log(this.state.annonces.length);
  }
```

Comment: you're also mutating the state.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the spread operator instead of trying to mutate your state array with `annonces.push()`

```
addAnonces = () => {
    this.setState({
      annonces: [...this.state.annonces, {
        nom: 'Nkodi Ngami',
        annonces:
          'Le monde est étonné par ces proesses, mais nous non (rire) il savait clairement ou il allait',
      }]
    });
  };
111
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spread operator (...)

```
this.setState({ 
annonces: [...this.state.annonces, { nom : "Nkodi Ngami", annonces: "Je n'ai jamais douté de mon fils, je savais qu'il sera un grand home" }}]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should definitely avoid in React is to mutate the state itself, `push` will modify the array in the state. You may try to use spread operator instead.

```
addAnonces = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        annonces: [
            ...previousState.annonces,
            {
                nom : "Nkodi Ngami",
                annonces: "Le monde est étonné par ces proesses, mais nous non (rire) il savait clairement ou il allait"
            },
        ],
    }), () => {
        console.log(this.state.annonces.length);
    });
}
```

And if you want to check the length of the `annonces`, you should put it in `setState` callback as `setState` happening in async